# Published MATLAB html code to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, matlab, plugins, publish

I want to know how can I publish my Matlab scripts into Wordpress?

I used Matlab publish function in order to get an html file which actually works when I open it with my browser.

However, my problem is when I tried to copy the html code and paste it into wordpress HTML, I don't get the same result. It looks like Wordpress cannot do the job.

What seems to be the problem there? Or do I need to install a Wordpress plugin or what?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you describe more properly what *exactly* you did? Did you simply copy the entire HTML code into a wordpress article?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use MATLAB tool for publishing MATLAB code to WordPress.

The more information is available in :

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/103730-publishing-tool-for-matlab-live-script-to-wordpress